# How _WIN32, __linux__... preprocessor macro work?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

How a C compiler like GCC defines the preprocessor macro to detect the current OS?

I looked into GCC's source code and found [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/config/i386/mingw32.h) `builtin_define ("_WIN32");` but I'm not sure if this is where the macros are defined.

Comment: Looks like possibly from within [gcc/config.host](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/config.host#L237) or line 245?

Comment: Notice that GCC doesn't actually *detect* these, it is just that it is the one that the compiler was *built with*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so is this like compiler bootstrapping, where one compiler binary get its preprocessors from the one it was built from, and so on until the first compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Basically, yes. The built-in macros are defined in a target description header file.

There is so often a Fine Manual To Read; in this case, it's the [GCC internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/). (Specifically, in the section on [Run-time target specification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Run-time-Target.html), but don't start reading there; you'll need some context.)

There is a [complete compendium of GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) in case you need more information. (The internals documents are at the bottom of that page.)

(If you're comfortable using the GNU info reader and you're using a Ubuntu/Debian system, you can install the GCC documentation for your current GCC version with `sudo apt-get install gcc-doc`; that includes the GCC internals documentation.)